# Populate checkboxes according to array count

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

im new to `php` and its developing i have used `php array`. I want to populate `checkboxes` according to array count. in oder to do that i have tried following way. it didnt work on me. Are there any way to do that (in my case array count= 5 so i need 5 checkboxes accordingly)

```
 <?php

         $chk_group =array('1' => 'red',
                               '2' => 'aa',
             '3' => 'th',
             '4' => 'ra',
             '5' => 'sara' 



         );

         var_dump($chk_group);

         //continue for loop

          for ($i=0 ; $i<count($chk_group);$i++)
     {
        // echo count($chk_group);
        echo"<input type="checkbox" value="$chk_group" name="chk_group[0]">" 
          echo $chk_group;  
     }


         ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending your echo strings prematurely by not escaping the quotations. See the problem here:

```
// See how the echo string ends at the beginning of the attributes for the input
// tag, and another string begins at the end? Need to escape the quotations.
echo "<input type="checkbox" value="some_value" name="some_name">";

// Something like this -- notice how the string ends where it should.
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"some_value\" name=\"some_name\">";
```

Another problem you have is your use of `<?php .. ?>` within PHP tags.

Additionally, you want to echo the values associated with the keys in your array. What you have here is an associative array (key => value pairs), as opposed to a more rudimentary array (indexed values).

Finally, you should ideally utilize a `foreach` loop with associative arrays. Below are readings I recommend you do.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

See: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php