# populate textboxes with values according to array count

Tags: php, arrays, textbox

I'm developing php application for the first time. There, I have used php arrays. I'm taking array values and show these values in html text boxes. In my code textboxes populate according to array count, but the value of the text box didn't show. Please help me to solve this issue, and please find below the code I used.

```
 <?php
     $chk_group =array(
         '1' => 'red',
         '2' => 'aa',
         '3' => 'bb',
         '4' => 'cc',
         '5' => 'dd' 
     );

     var_dump($chk_group);

     //continue for loop

     for ($i=0 ; $i<count($chk_group);$i++)
     {   
         $val =$chk_group[$i];
         //echo $val; tested problem is with below $val is not displaying just after the //check box
         echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$val\" name=\"chk_group\">";
     }


     ?>
```

Comment: You asked this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/27585903/ and accepted an answer; what's different from that question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- problem is value isn't displaying just after the checkbox

Comment: What do you mean, I don't see anything after `echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$val\" name=\"chk_group\">";`

Comment: What do you mean the value isn't displaying after the checkbox? Do you mean you want the contents of $val to appear as text right after the checkbox?

Comment: @Memento Mori your correct dude

Comment: The way you asked your question, doesn't even come close to what Memento just happened to figure out. Had you expressed yourself in saying what you wanted to echo, I'd of given you an answer 5 seconds after you posted it.

Comment: @ Fred -ii thank you dude. i should improve that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really asking is how to display text for a checkbox. Value isn't the field to set that, value is only used when the form is submitted. You just write it as text after your checkbox. So for example:

`<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test">text to appear after checkbox`

or in your case:

`echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $val . '" name="chk_group">' . $val;`

Answer (score 0):

Try out following code:

```
$chk_group =array(
     '1' => 'red',
     '2' => 'aa',
     '3' => 'bb',
     '4' => 'cc',
     '5' => 'dd' 
 );

 foreach( $chk_group as $key=>$value ){
     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chk_group' value='".$value."' />";
 }
```

Comment: it didnt work. all i need is the contents of $val to appear as text right after the checkbox as value. this didnt do that values of check box not displaying right after the check box

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_value(i){
    var j = document.getElementById('chk_'+i).value;
    document.getElementById('chk').value = j;
}
</script>
<?php

$chk_group =array(
    '1' => 'red',
    '2' => 'aa',
    '3' => 'bb',
    '4' => 'cc',
    '5' => 'dd' 
    );

var_dump($chk_group);

for ($i=1;$i<=count($chk_group);$i++){
?>
    <input type='checkbox' value=<?=$chk_group[$i]?> name='chk_group' onclick='get_value(<?=$i?>)' id="chk_<?=$i?>">
<?php
}
?>
<input type="text" name="chk" id="chk">
```

Comment: it didnt work. all i need is  the contents of $val to appear as text right after the checkbox as value. this didnt do that values of check box not displaying right after the check box